# Full Calendar Events Disappear After Refresh or Reloading Page

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, plugins, fullcalendar

I have Full Calendar in my page and whenever I drag and drop an event from the Draggable Events to a calendar date and REFRESH/RELOAD the page, the dragged event disappears.
[image]

How do I let a newly created and dragged event stay in place whenever I refresh or reload the page? This is still my first time using Full Calendar so I'm still not familiar with it.

Here's my source code:

```
<div class='col-md-12'>
    <div class="box box-success">
        <!-- Content Header (Page header) -->
        <div class="box-header with-border">
            <section class="content-header">
                <h1>Calendar</h1>
            </section>
        </div>

        <!-- Main content -->
        <section class="content">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-3">
                    <div class="box box-solid">
                        <div class="box-header with-border">
                            <h4 class="box-title">Draggable Events</h4>
                        </div>
                        <div class="box-body">
                        <!-- the events -->
                            <div id="external-events">
                                <div class="external-event bg-green">Lunch</div>
                                <div class="external-event bg-yellow">Go home</div>
                                <div class="external-event bg-aqua">Do homework</div>
                                <div class="external-event bg-light-blue">Work on UI design</div>
                                <div class="external-event bg-red">Sleep tight</div>
                                <div class="checkbox">
                                    <label for="drop-remove">
                                        <input type="checkbox" id="drop-remove">
                                        remove after drop
                                    </label>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div><!-- /.box-body -->
                    </div><!-- /. box -->
                    <div class="box box-solid">
                        <div class="box-header with-border">
                            <h3 class="box-title">Create Event</h3>
                        </div>
                        <div class="box-body">
                            <div class="btn-group" style="width: 100%; margin-bottom: 10px;">
                                <!--<button type="button" id="color-chooser-btn" class="btn btn-info btn-block dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">Color <span class="caret"></span></button>-->
                                <ul class="fc-color-picker" id="color-chooser">
                                    <li><a class="text-aqua" href="#"><i class="fa fa-square"></i></a></li>
                                    <li><a class="text-blue" href="#"><i class="fa fa-square"></i></a></li>
                                    <li><a class="text-light-blue" href="#"><i class="fa fa-square"></i></a></li>
                                    <li><a class="text-teal" href="#"><i class="fa fa-square"></i></a></li>
                                    <li><a class="text-yellow" href="#"><i class="fa fa-square"></i></a></li>
                                    <li><a class="text-orange" href="#"><i class="fa fa-square"></i></a></li>
                                    <li><a class="text-green" href="#"><i class="fa fa-square"></i></a></li>
                                    <li><a class="text-lime" href="#"><i class="fa fa-square"></i></a></li>
                                    <li><a class="text-red" href="#"><i class="fa fa-square"></i></a></li>
                                    <li><a class="text-purple" href="#"><i class="fa fa-square"></i></a></li>
                                    <li><a class="text-fuchsia" href="#"><i class="fa fa-square"></i></a></li>
                                    <li><a class="text-muted" href="#"><i class="fa fa-square"></i></a></li>
                                    <li><a class="text-navy" href="#"><i class="fa fa-square"></i></a></li>
                                </ul>
                            </div><!-- /btn-group -->
                            <div class="input-group">
                                <input id="new-event" type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Event Title">
                                <div class="input-group-btn">
                                    <button id="add-new-event" type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-flat">Add</button>
                                </div><!-- /btn-group -->
                            </div><!-- /input-group -->
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div><!-- /.col -->
                <div class="col-md-9">
                    <div class="box box-primary">
                        <div class="box-body no-padding">
                            <!-- THE CALENDAR -->
                            <div id="calendar"></div>
                        </div><!-- /.box-body -->
                    </div><!-- /. box -->
                </div><!-- /.col -->
            </div><!-- /.row -->
        </section><!-- /.content -->
    </div>
</div><!-- /.content-wrapper -->

<script type="text/javascript">
/* Calendar */
$(function () {
    /* initialize the external events
     -----------------------------------------------------------------*/
    function ini_events(ele) {
        ele.each(function () {

            // create an Event Object (http://arshaw.com/fullcalendar/docs/event_data/Event_Object/)
            // it doesn't need to have a start or end
            var eventObject = {
                title: $.trim($(this).text()) // use the element's text as the event title
            };

            // store the Event Object in the DOM element so we can get to it later
            $(this).data('eventObject', eventObject);

            // make the event draggable using jQuery UI
            $(this).draggable({
                zIndex: 1070,
                revert: true, // will cause the event to go back to its
                revertDuration: 0  //  original position after the drag
            });
        });
    }
    ini_events($('#external-events div.external-event'));

    /* initialize the calendar
     -----------------------------------------------------------------*/
    //Date for the calendar events (dummy data)
    var date = new Date();
    var d = date.getDate(),
            m = date.getMonth(),
            y = date.getFullYear();

    $('#calendar').fullCalendar({
        header: {
            left: 'prev,next today',
            center: 'title',
            right: 'month,agendaWeek,agendaDay'
        },
        buttonText: {
            today: 'today',
            month: 'month',
            week: 'week',
            day: 'day'
        },
        //Random default events
        events: [
            {
                title: 'New Year\'s Day',
                start: '2015-01-01',
                backgroundColor: "#f56954",
                borderColor: "#f56954" 
            },
            {
                title: 'First Chinese New Year',
                start: '2015-02-19',
                backgroundColor: "#f39c12", 
                borderColor: "#f39c12" 
            },
            {
                title: 'Second Chinese New Year',
                start: '2015-02-20',
                backgroundColor: "#0073b7", 
                borderColor: "#0073b7" 
            },
            {
                title: 'Good Friday',
                start: '2015-04-03',
                backgroundColor: "#00c0ef", 
                borderColor: "#00c0ef" 
            },
            {
                title: 'Labor Day',
                start: '2015-05-01',
                backgroundColor: "#00a65a", 
                borderColor: "#00a65a" 
            },
            {
                title: 'Vesak Day',
                start: '2015-06-01',
                backgroundColor: "#3c8dbc", 
                borderColor: "#3c8dbc" 
            },
            {
                title: 'Hari Raya Puasa',
                start: '2015-07-17',
                backgroundColor: "#f39c12", 
                borderColor: "#f39c12" 
            },
            {
                title: 'SG 50 Public Holiday',
                start: '2015-08-07',
                backgroundColor: "#0073b7", 
                borderColor: "#0073b7" 
            },
            {
                title: 'National Day',
                start: '20150-80-97',
                backgroundColor: "#00c0ef", 
                borderColor: "#00c0ef" 
            },
            {
                title: 'Hari Raya Haji',
                start: '2015-09-24',
                backgroundColor: "#00c0ef", 
                borderColor: "#00c0ef" 
            },
            {
                title: 'Deepavali',
                start: '2015-11-10',
                backgroundColor: "#00a65a", 
                borderColor: "#00a65a" 
            },
            {
                title: 'Christmas Day',
                start: '2015-12-25',
                backgroundColor: "#3c8dbc", 
                borderColor: "#3c8dbc" 
            },
        /*{
          title: 'All Day Event',
          start: new Date(y, m, 1),
          backgroundColor: "#f56954", //red
          borderColor: "#f56954" //red
        },
        {
          title: 'Long Event',
          start: new Date(y, m, d - 5),
          end: new Date(y, m, d - 2),
          backgroundColor: "#f39c12", //yellow
          borderColor: "#f39c12" //yellow
        },
        {
          title: 'Meeting',
          start: new Date(y, m, d, 10, 30),
          allDay: false,
          backgroundColor: "#0073b7", //Blue
          borderColor: "#0073b7" //Blue
        },
        {
          title: 'Lunch',
          start: new Date(y, m, d, 12, 0),
          end: new Date(y, m, d, 14, 0),
          allDay: false,
          backgroundColor: "#00c0ef", //Info (aqua)
          borderColor: "#00c0ef" //Info (aqua)
        },
        {
          title: 'Birthday Party',
          start: new Date(y, m, d + 1, 19, 0),
          end: new Date(y, m, d + 1, 22, 30),
          allDay: false,
          backgroundColor: "#00a65a", //Success (green)
          borderColor: "#00a65a" //Success (green)
        },
        {
          title: 'Click for Google',
          start: new Date(y, m, 28),
          end: new Date(y, m, 29),
          url: 'http://google.com/',
          backgroundColor: "#3c8dbc", //Primary (light-blue)
          borderColor: "#3c8dbc" //Primary (light-blue)
        }*/
        ],
        editable: true,
        droppable: true, // this allows things to be dropped onto the calendar !!!
        drop: function (date, allDay) { // this function is called when something is dropped

        // retrieve the dropped element's stored Event Object
        var originalEventObject = $(this).data('eventObject');

        // we need to copy it, so that multiple events don't have a reference to the same object
        var copiedEventObject = $.extend({}, originalEventObject);

        // assign it the date that was reported
        copiedEventObject.start = date;
        copiedEventObject.allDay = allDay;
        copiedEventObject.backgroundColor = $(this).css("background-color");
        copiedEventObject.borderColor = $(this).css("border-color");

        // render the event on the calendar
        // the last `true` argument determines if the event "sticks" (http://arshaw.com/fullcalendar/docs/event_rendering/renderEvent/)
        $('#calendar').fullCalendar('renderEvent', copiedEventObject, true);

        // is the "remove after drop" checkbox checked?
        if ($('#drop-remove').is(':checked')) {
            // if so, remove the element from the "Draggable Events" list
            $(this).remove();
            }
        }
    });

    /* ADDING EVENTS */
    var currColor = "#3c8dbc"; //Red by default
    //Color chooser button
    var colorChooser = $("#color-chooser-btn");
    $("#color-chooser > li > a").click(function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        //Save color
        currColor = $(this).css("color");
        //Add color effect to button
        $('#add-new-event').css({"background-color": currColor, "border-color": currColor});
    });
    $("#add-new-event").click(function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        //Get value and make sure it is not null
        var val = $("#new-event").val();
        if (val.length == 0) {
            return;
        }

        //Create events
        var event = $("<div />");
        event.css({"background-color": currColor, "border-color": currColor, "color": "#fff"}).addClass("external-event");
        event.html(val);
        $('#external-events').prepend(event);

        //Add draggable funtionality
        ini_events(event);

        //Remove event from text input
        $("#new-event").val("");
    });
});
</script>
```

Hope somebody could help.

Answer (score 1):

You should save the events first whenever a drop occurs(we do it on db). Then you can retrieve and assign them to calendar on refresh or reload.

Here is an example of how to specify an array of events on calendar startup.

http://fullcalendar.io/docs/event_data/events_array/

You can set events from ajax call too. Here is an example:

http://fullcalendar.io/docs/event_data/events_function/